# Is it possible to use the "IsBlank()" function on a function's result?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, is-empty

I have created a function, where I would like to have a blank result in some cases, in order to use the `IsBlank()` function on it afterwards, but this seems not possible, as you can see from this example (the top row contains the used formulae):

[image]

As you see, the column "E" formula sometimes results in an empty string, but in Excel, an empty string is not blank (`=IsBlank("")` seems to yield `FALSE`).

Is there an Excel constant of function I can use as a "blank" result?

Comment: Not really, according to this: https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-isblank-function

Comment: Then what is end goal to use of `=IsBlank()`.

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis: I have understood from your URL that checking on the length of a cell is a good way to check whether the cell is blank or just contains an empty string. You can write this as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IsBlank` tests if a cell is `Empty`.  An empty string is != an empty cell.  A regular formula cannot return `Empty`.  So the answer to your Q is No.